# How to get rid of the initial "To access this page, you have to log in" on an experience site?

Tags: experience-cloud, login-errors

We have an experience site set up. It's all protected and published on a custom domain url.
Whenever the user enters the url to the browser (e.g. https://www.example.com ) she'll be taken to the login page, however there is already a red error message "To access this page you have to log in to Example Portal.".

This is because salesforce redirects https://www.example.com to https://www.example.com/s which is redirected to https://www.example.com/login?ec=302&startURL=%2Fs%2F.

This is pretty annoying. Is there a way around this?

The expected behavior would be a simple https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com/login without any message.

The site works otherwise without issues, this is just a small annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure your Experience Cloud site is both active in the Administration settings of the Site but also Published from within the Experience Builder.